# Pass <Img/> Gatsby to React Button to create full interactive images grid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, gatsby-image

I try to make a full button grid of images with Gatsby that's almost work but when I pass the component `<Img/>` that's change a little the height of my button and add an empty line at the top or the button I don't know. I don't know why and I don't find any information about the solution to solve it. Here is a little piece of my code if it can help.

```
function Cell({ children, ...props }) {
  // ... code
  console.log("Cell() cell props", props.w, props.h)
  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={toggle_cell}
        className="cell"
        style={set_button_style(props, is, mouse_is)}
      >
        {
          <Img
            fluid={children.childImageSharp.fluid}
            Tag="div"
          />
        }
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Style

```
const set_button_style = (props, select_is, mouse_is) => {
  let alpha = 0
  select_is ? (alpha = 1) : (alpha = 0.5)
  let border_is
  let hex_color = hsb_to_hex(0.5, 1, 0)
  mouse_is ? (border_is = `10px solid ${hex_color}`) : (border_is = `0`)
  return {
    background: `${hsb_to_hex(0, 0, 0)}`,
    opacity: alpha,
    width: `${props.w}px`,
    height: `${props.h}px`,
    border: border_is,
    padding: 0,
  }
}
```

An example to illustrate my problem: The size display by the Dev Tool React is `456px x 463px` for the `Cell` and indicate `456px x 456px` for `Image`, and the children props indicate `h:456 w:456` like I wish. And the result is a non-acceptable beautiful yellow line :)

to see what's happen in live https://stanlab.netlify.app/grid_button_advanced/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you add a `height: 100%` to the image itself and a `width: 100%` and `height: 100%` in the `gatsby-image-wrapper` it displays:

[image]

It's better to use relative variables rather than absolute or magic numbers to avoid these behaviours when styling, in most cases the image or the container will adapt its size to the wrapper if it's properly set.

Comment: I understand the goal but what is the `gatsby-image-wrapper`? I don't find it in my project.

Comment: It's the wrapper that Gatsby adds to the `<Img>` component so, if you are using styled-components, wrap the `<Img>` to a custom component. If you are using other styling ways, just add the class and syle it.

Comment: I don't understand where I must change the `gatsby-image-wrapper`. I try to do something like that ```<Img
            class="gatsby-image-wrapper"
            style={{ height: "100%", width: "100%" }}
            height="100%"
            // style="width: 100%; height: 100%"
            fluid={children.childImageSharp.fluid}
            // Tag="div"
          /> ``` but that's change nothing.

Comment: How are you styling your project? Using styled-components? CSS modules? CSS files? It seems that you have some styling using CSS files, so, add there a `.gatsby-image-wrapper` and add the styles there. PS: it should be `className` rather than `class`

Comment: Yes I use the style CSS and module to... but I don't understand exactly how I must use it, it's very messy for me. I'v one named layout.css and other one name global.css and other one named container.module.css ... I think it's gone for a long time for me to understand this strange world of internet jungle :(

Comment: You are mixing things... Take a look at https://www.gatsbyjs.com/tutorial/part-two/ Just add `gatsby-image-wrapper` and style as I said

Comment: I do this tutorial before, but may be I must do it again!!!